# 3DExperience: switch product to edit mode

Tags: vba, catia

how can I **switch** a product in 3DExperience **to edit mode**?

From the user interface this can simply be achieved by right-clicking the product:

[image]

In Catia V5 it was easily done with

```
prdRoot.ApplyWorkMode DESIGN_MODE
```

I cannot find anything in the docu.
What is the equivalent API-method in VBA for 3DX?

Answer (score 0):

You can always select the product  (search by name, for example) and use CATIA.StartCommand .....

Comment: Methods that do not need the selection are preferable. So I hoped I would not need StartCommand here. I also did not find **the correct StartCommand string**. 
Could you please replace the "....." by the correct string? (if found some _"CATMnoDbgSwitchToEditModeHdr"_ in the docs but this throws an error)

Comment: Other drawback with _StartCommand_  (besides requiring the selection): the code does not wait until execution is finished